# C++ My form should stay on top of every kind of windows

Tags: c++, modal-dialog

I have a main form. This main form generate another form. This new form should be fill before having access to other window. I used Myform.ShowDialog() to make this form modal.

I would like that my form will be on top of every type of other windows even if these windows are not part of my application (for example: Internet explorer page, opened Word document...).

Do you any solution ??

Thanks,

Comment: That is very obnoxious program behavior.  Do you *really* have a valid reason for blocking all of the user's applications?  I doubt it.

Comment: I doubt that there's really a way to do that, because what if 2 applications both did that? Which would be in front?

Comment: There are ways to do it, but it is annoying and likely unjustified.

Comment: Just don't do it.  There is a special place in hell for programmers who try to dictate the way that I work.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using .NET

In which case you can use the Form.TopMost property

```
myForm->TopMost = true;
myForm->ShowDialog();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using Form.TopMost will make the window appear above any other window in your application, but it does not work other applications.

While I have seen apps that make their window float on top of all other windows, I don't think you can make a modal dialog box that prevents you from using other applications.

A really dirty hack would be to have a timer the forces your window to the foreground every second. It means that users would not be able to use any other application in a meaningful way, but *they will definitely hate you for it*.

You could also try simulating the Windows Vista/7 -style UAC dialog by taking a snapshot of the desktop, making a full-screen window with that image in it, and then rendering your window on top. However, experience shows that users don't like those UAC dialogs either.

Comment: Not true, fire up visual studio and try it. Make a new forms application (in C# for example), and in the Load method, set this.TopMost = true. Then focus another window on top of it. This functionality has been present at least since Windows 95, maybe longer. Traditionally it has been referred to as "Always on top"

Comment: This is true if it was your application on focus at the time the dialog will pupop. But if the focus is on internet explorer when the dialog popup the windows will stay in the back until you will select it. 

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

won't [form->DoModal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5(VS.80).aspx) do the trick? (works in MFC anyways?)

Comment: I think this will work within the application but does not stay on top of windows from other programs.

Comment: This is as good as you can get in windows AFAIK. It used to be possible in windows 3.1, maybe even windows 95, but no longer. Good thing too, annoying behaviour :-)

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen proved why it's impossible:

Imagine if it was possible for applications to do this, you did, and another application did this too. Now obviously that application would be on top of every windows, including yours, yet your application would be on top of every other window, including theirs. It's a logical impossibility that your window is on top of theirs AND their window is on top of yours. Hence it follows logically that it is not possible for any application to claim the topmost window.

Comment: one of the windows would be topmost

Comment: Obviously, violating the premise that the other application could make its window topmost.